# Correct usage of "promise" as a noun

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> I can't give you any promise that your late response will be
> acknowledged.
>
> Again, I can't give you any promise [for/about/on] that.

Is any of the above cases correct? I'm particularly asking about the preposition that comes after "give somebody a promise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't give you any **promises** *that* your late response will be acknowledged.

It should be *promises* because [it's a countable noun.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/promise)

> Again, I can't give you any promises **about** that.

[*about* and *of*](https://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=promise) collocate well with *promise*, but I don't see anything particularly wrong with the other two.

A sentence with promise as a verb

> I can't promise you anything/it.

would be more common, though.